# Run command on new frame with daemon/client in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dvorak, emacsclient

This is perhaps quite simple, but I haven't found anything useful when googling. So here it goes :)

I use Emacs in daemon mode (`emacs --daemon`) and it's really handy. I also use dvorak and have found that remapping <kbd>C-j</kbd> to <kbd>C-c</kbd> (and vice versa) is really handy in the long run, and use the following for making that translation:

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-j ?\C-c)
(keyboard-translate ?\C-c ?\C-j)
```

This works great when *not* using Emacs as a daemon. When I start a new client (cli/gui) <kbd>C-j</kbd> is no longer bound to <kbd>C-c</kbd>. Whaaat?

So I guess I'll need to run the `keyboard-translate` after creating a new client frame, but I have no idea how to do it. I've tried with a `defadvice` I found somewhere, but couldn't make it work so I gave up and removed it.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `keyboard-translate` <kbd>RET</kbd> says that:

> This variable has a separate binding for each terminal.  See Info node
> `(elisp)Multiple displays'.

which points us in the right direction, although there's an error in that documentation, as the referenced info node doesn't exist. A search suggests that the node is actually renamed `(elisp)Multiple terminals`, which you can also read here: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multiple-Terminals.html

> On GNU and Unix systems, each X display is a separate graphical terminal [...] Emacs can even connect to other text-only terminals, by interacting with the emacsclient program.

So when you start emacs as a daemon, you have not yet connected to a terminal (or at least, not to one that is useful to you), and so your commands do not generate bindings for the terminal(s) that you end up using.

The `after-make-frame-functions` variable provides one way to resolve this.

```
(defun my-dvorak-translations (&optional frame)
  "Re-map keys in the current terminal."
  (with-selected-frame (or frame (selected-frame))
    (keyboard-translate ?\C-j ?\C-c)
    (keyboard-translate ?\C-c ?\C-j)))
;; Evaluate both now (for non-daemon emacs) and upon frame creation
;; (for new terminals via emacsclient).
(my-dvorak-translations)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-dvorak-translations)
```

Experimentally it appears safe to repeat your commands, so we don't need to worry about only executing this once per terminal (but if we did, we could use `(get-device-terminal FRAME)` to help with that).

Answer (score 2):

To expand on phils' answer:

On Emacs 26.1 I had to run the keyboard translations in the context of the new frame, like so:

```
(defun make-keyboard-translations ()
  (keyboard-translate ?\C-j ?\C-c))

(defun setup-frame-keyboard (frame)
  (with-selected-frame frame
    (make-keyboard-translations)))

(make-keyboard-translations)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'setup-frame-keyboard)
```

Comment: I don't know whether `after-make-frame-functions` was auto-selecting the frame back then or not, but it certainly hasn't done so anytime recently... I was a bit startled to find this old answer and notice my bug.  Glad to see you'd added this correction.

Answer (score 0):

Another hook that is run each time emacsclient is invoked is `server-visit-hook`, which is perhaps more appropriate than `after-make-frame-functions`.

```
(add-hook 'server-visit-hook 
     (lambda ()
          (keyboard-translate ?\C-j ?\C-c)
          (keyboard-translate ?\C-c ?\C-j)))
```

Comment: Would that account for the situation where a new client/frame is opened *without* a file list?