# Emacs: Rebind numbers (Editor of the Beast VI VI VI)

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Just coming to Emacs from vi.

I'd like to rebind all the numbers across the top of the keyboard to their shifted counterparts (i.e. 1 maps to !, 2 maps to @, etc), while at the same time keeping the numerical keypad numbers as simply numbers.

I remapped the numbers just fine, and the numbers across the top of the keyboard map to symbols correctly; however this also maps the keypad numbers to symbols.  In response I tried to remap the keypad numbers back to numbers again but this is unsuccessful - they stay as symbols.

This was straightforward and easy to accomplish when I was using vi, but I would prefer to keep using Emacs.  Anyone have a solution?

Sample .emacs:

```
(global-set-key "1" "!")
; etc...

(global-set-key [kp-1] "1")
; etc...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<kp-1>") "1")
(keyboard-translate ?1 ?!)
```

I would actually use `xmodmap` to change the keys across the whole
system, not just Emacs.

Comment: You may wish to take a look at this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5066313/324105

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```lisp
(global-set-key "1" "!")
(global-set-key [kp-1] (lambda () (interactive) (insert "1")))
```

P.S. I use (lambda () (interactive) ...) in `global-set-key` frequently and create alias for it:

```lisp
(defmacro ilam (&rest body)
  "Interactive lambda"
  `(lambda ()
     (interactive)
     ,@body))
```