# Emacs Client fires up a "clean" (ignores init files) Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am trying to use Emacs Client. I am on OSX. so:

```
alias ec="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -n -c -a -nw /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs"
```

Then I put `(start-server)` on my init.el file. A\and:

```
e --daemon
```

So when I run `ec`. And a clean Emacs instance is fired up.

Whats is wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters `-c` and `-nw` are incompatible, and you appear to have inserted the `-nw` in between `-a` and its parameter. If fixing that doesn't help, what happens when you start the daemon and run plain `emacsclient -c` ?

Comment: hi @phils. Yeah, I just remove all options and use only -c, then emacs start on graphical mode. But not load my emacs.d configurations...

Comment: It's the server which has to load your config. Try connecting again, issue `M-x kill-emacs` to kill the server, then start again with `emacs --daemon` (not using any alias), and see if your config is loaded.

Comment: Hi, I am using alias because I want use Emacs installation under /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS and not OS X own emacs version....

Comment: Fair enough; I was just trying to minimise the potential sources of weirdness (e.g. the alias used `-q` or `-Q`), but obviously you'll still want to run the intended version :)

Comment: it seems that the configurations were initializadas correctly, only a few who do not ... perhaps the reason being loaded from the temrinal...

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5066313/324105 -- can you confirm, please?

Comment: I think not. At least don't make effect here...

Comment: In that case you'll need to provide details of what isn't working. You might want to close this question and ask a new one, as the real problem is clearly different to what you originally thought.

Comment: Yes @phils. I will close this question. I will take a look more calmly. Thanks for now.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem seems init.el is ignored when running as a daemon